# Wordpress: Issue with filtering users using date range

Tags: filters, wp-admin, users

I'm trying to add a date range filter for wordpress admin users table to filter users that have posted ads between the selected range. I've managed to add the date range inputs.

[image]

I have 2 issues with this approach.

1. When I hit filter the selected date doesn't bind to the query (like date_from=2018-11-28), with the text input.

   `<input type="text" id="date-from" name="date_from" autocomplete="off">`

   Then I used a hidden `select` input with the same name and set the value using jquery when date input is changed.( This is not good, but solve the issue)

   What's the issue with the input. Can't I use a text input in filters ?
2. To add the filter query I used `pre_get_users` . But it doesn't filter users

   ```
   add_filter( 'pre_get_users', 'filter_users' );
   function filter_users( $query ) {
   global $pagenow;

   if ( is_admin() &&  'users.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_GET[ 'date_from' ] ) || isset( $_GET[ 'date_to' ] ) ) {

       $date_from = isset( $_GET[ 'date_from' ] ) ? $_GET['date_from'] : null;
       $date_to = isset( $_GET[ 'date_to' ] ) ? $_GET['date_to'] : null;

       $date_where = '';

       if( ! empty($date_from) > 0 && ! empty($date_to) > 0){
           $date_where = "DATE(wp_posts.post_date) >= '$date_from' AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) < '$date_to'";
       }else if( ! empty($date_from)){
           $date_where = "DATE(wp_posts.post_date) >= '$date_from'";
       }else if( ! empty($date_to)){
           $date_where = "DATE(wp_posts.post_date) < '$date_to'";
       }

       if( empty($query->query_where) ){
           $query->query_where = "INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID WHERE $date_where";
       }else{

           $query->query_where = str_replace( "WHERE 1=1', 'INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID WHERE 1=1 AND $date_where", $query->query_where);
       }

   }
   }
   ```

What is the reason for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A sidenote, but your queries don't check the post type of the posts, so they'll pick up posts, pages, attachments, nav menu items, autosaves, revisions, etc etc

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for the note. But It should return empty if I choose a future date. right?  It's not

Comment: Used `pre_user_query` instead of `pre_get_users` and i'ts working